# Can't declare lists in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim lstNum As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() { 3, 6, 7, 9 })
```

When I type the above line of code, Visual Studio informs me of an error

> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.List' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments.

What on earth does that mean and how do I fix it? I can't seem to create lists of any kind. I'm assuming I'm missing some sort of import but I'm not fluent with VB.Net enough to know what to try.

Comment: You are not missing an import, it appears you have an extra one for `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

Comment: I had none declared; perhaps since I had no imports it chose the first one it found in the list - Microsoft comes before System in the listing of imports...

Comment: BTW, I bet you "do have imports declared", but don't realize it, because the "declaration" is in your VB Project's Properties, References tab, "Imported namespaces". That applies to ALL .vb files in your project. (I mention this, in case a future reader doesn't know they should look there.) Go there, UNCHECK Microsoft...Word. Then add Word ONLY to files that need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Generic.List instead of just List.

```
Dim lstNum As New Generic.List(Of Integer)(New Integer() { 3, 6, 7, 9 })
```

Since you have the Word interop imported, it is trying to find Word.List. Specifying Generic.List will tell it to go outside of that import.

Comment: THANKS! that's it! (It's making me wait 11minutes to accept but this will be accepted)

Comment: More specifically ensure you are importing and/or aliasing the System.Collections.Generic namespace.  Generic.List won't necessarily work unless he's imported System.Collections.

Comment: Not sure of the situations, but I don't have to import System.Collections.Generic. Maybe because I am using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `System.Collections.Generic`

```
 Dim lstNum As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)(New Integer() { 3, 6, 7, 9 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Either You use Generic.list instead of List    Dim lstNum As New Generic.List(Of Integer)(New Integer() { 3, 6, 7, 9 })  Or you just import System.Collections.Generic Namespace, Both approaches are fine, but I'd go for the later one if I've to use list again and again. .